# Цепочка вызовов не сохраняет предыдущий результат

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы предыдущий add(2, 'years) прибавил 2 года, сохранил, а потом add(1, 'years') прибавил к уже сохраненному результату еще 1 год?

```
var time = function (date) {
  var arr = date.split(/[\s-:]/);

  var objTime = {
    newDate: new Date (arr[0], arr[1] - 1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]),

    add: function (value, string) {

      if (value > 0) {
         if (string == 'years') {
          this.newDate.setFullYear(value + +arr[0]);
          return this;
         }
         else if (string == 'months') {
          myDate.setMonth(value + +arr[1]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
         }
         else if (string == 'days') {
          myDate.setMonth(arr[1] - 1, value + +arr[2]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
         }
         else if (string == 'hours') {
          myDate.setHours(value + +arr[3]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
         }
         else if (string == 'minutes') {
          myDate.setMinutes(value + +arr[4]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
         } else {
          return TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
         }
      } else {
        return TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
      }
  },

  substract: function (value, string) {
    if (value > 0) {
       if (string == 'years') {
        myDate.setFullYear(+arr[0] - value);
        this.newDate = myDate;
        return this;
       }
       else if (string == 'months') {
        myDate.setMonth(+arr[1] - value);
        this.newDate = myDate;
        return this;
       }
       else if (string == 'days') {
        myDate.setMonth(arr[1] - 1, +arr[2] - value);
        this.newDate = myDate;
        return this;
       }
       else if (string == 'hours') {
        myDate.setHours(+arr[3] - value);
        this.newDate = myDate;
        return this;
       }
       else if (string == 'minutes') {
        myDate.setMinutes(+arr[4] - value);
        this.newDate = myDate
        return this;
       } else {
        throw new TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
       }
    } else {
      throw new TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
    }
  }
};

  return objTime;

};

console.log(time('2017-05-16 13:45').add(2, 'years').add(1, 'years'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте `arr` в `add` и `subtract`. Я исправил для `add - years`.

Что такое `myDate`?

```js
var time = function(date) {
  var arr = date.split(/[\s-:]/);

  var objTime = {
    newDate: new Date(arr[0], arr[1] - 1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]),

    add: function(value, string) {

      if (value > 0) {
        if (string == 'years') {
          this.newDate.setFullYear(value + this.newDate.getFullYear());
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'months') {
          myDate.setMonth(value + +arr[1]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'days') {
          myDate.setMonth(arr[1] - 1, value + +arr[2]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'hours') {
          myDate.setHours(value + +arr[3]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'minutes') {
          myDate.setMinutes(value + +arr[4]);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else {
          return TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
        }
      } else {
        return TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
      }
    },

    substract: function(value, string) {
      if (value > 0) {
        if (string == 'years') {
          myDate.setFullYear(+arr[0] - value);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'months') {
          myDate.setMonth(+arr[1] - value);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'days') {
          myDate.setMonth(arr[1] - 1, +arr[2] - value);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'hours') {
          myDate.setHours(+arr[3] - value);
          this.newDate = myDate;
          return this;
        } else if (string == 'minutes') {
          myDate.setMinutes(+arr[4] - value);
          this.newDate = myDate
          return this;
        } else {
          throw new TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
        }
      } else {
        throw new TypeError('Передано неверное значение');
      }
    }
  };

  return objTime;

};

console.log(time('2017-05-16 13:45').add(2, 'years').add(1, 'years'));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: myDate я уже убрал, это была переменная из моих прошлых вариантов решения